# Visual Studio 2010: How Can I remap F2 to Rename File rather than Open Object Browser

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, solution-explorer, remap

In Visual Studio 2010 Solution Explorer tree view, how can I remap the <kbd>F2</kbd> key to Rename the Selected File rather than open Object Browser?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Do the following

- Tools -> Options
- Expand Environment and select Keyboard
- Type "File.Rename" into the text box
- Put the Focus on the "Press Shortcut keys" box and hit <kbd>F2</kbd>
- Click Assign

Comment: Works for Visual Studio 2012 too!

Answer (score 1):

To enable the renaming of an identifier or method, etc. using the F2 key (i.e a variable or a method name), do the following:

- Tools -> Options
- Expand Environment and select Keyboard
- Type "Refactor.Rename" into the text box that says 'Show commands containing'
- Put the Focus on the "Press Shortcut keys" box and hit F2
- Click Assign

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about you, but in my copy of VS2010, <kbd>F2</kbd> in the Solution Explorer DOES rename the file. What exactly do you have selected when you hit <kbd>F2</kbd>?

Comment: The OP likely selected the Visual Basic profile which maps F2 to object browser.

Comment: It opens the Object Browser for me, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Comment: Jared, you're probably right - my keyboard mapping was set to Vis C# 2005 mode. Was just about to edit my answer to provide actual content, but you beat me to it. +1

Comment: See Jared's answer to this question, Gordon. :)