# Is there a Visual Studio keyboard shortcut to rename a file in Solution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, rename

As the question title says: Is there a Visual Studio keyboard shortcut (or series of shortcuts) to rename file in Solution Explorer?

I am using VS2008 and manually doing this by right-clicking on a file in the Solution Explorer and selecting 'Rename', but this is a pain in the behind.

Comment: In general, you can customize the keyboard shortvuts to whatever you like. However, also check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375444/visual-studio-2010-how-can-i-remap-f2-to-rename-file-rather-than-open-object-bro

Comment: @InSane.  Thanks for the link.  Yet another example of how suckful the SO onsite searching is.  That link didn't come up in the Ask Question related answer prompt.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Depends on your settings profile:

In the C# profile, <kbd>F2</kbd> does this.

you can assign a shortcut to any key:

- Tools -> Options, Expand Environment and select Keyboard
- Enter `File.Rename` into the text box
- Put the Focus on the "Press Shortcut keys" box and hit 'the key you want to assign'
- Click Assign

Comment: Nice, that sorted it.  Thanks Mitch.

Comment: just btw F2 is also the default keyboard shortcut for rename in windows explorer

Answer (score 1):

No use option Refractor.Rename and Assign key to that say F2

Answer (score 0):

Use: [File Utils Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sleistner.vscode-fileutils)

command T or control T >File Utils: Rename, that's it.